# Start Filebeat using Supervisor

Tags: docker, supervisord, filebeat

So I have a CentOS Docker image containing Filebeat and a few other services which I'm trying to manage using Supervisor. As part of the Supervisor configuration, I want to start the Filebeat service. Here's what I'm trying in supervisord.conf

```
[program:filebeat]
command=/etc/init.d/filebeat start
directory=/etc/init.d/
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

The snippet above gives me an error stating "Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted".

Any thoughts on what's the right way to start Filebeat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend running Filebeat in its own [container](https://github.com/elastic/beats-docker#filebeat). But if you are going to use supervisord then you don't want to daemonize the process. You will want to use a command that's similar to what Filebeat uses for [systemd](https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/v5.2.2/dev-tools/packer/platforms/centos/systemd.j2).

```
command=/usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat -e
    -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml 
    -path.home /usr/share/filebeat
    -path.config /etc/filebeat
    -path.data /var/lib/filebeat
    -path.logs /var/log/filebeat
```

The `-e` tells the process to writes its logs to stderr so you can manage logging with `supervisorctl`.

Comment: I simply went ahead with having Filebeat in a separate container instead of using Supervisord to avoid the complexities.

Comment: I have a similar scenario where I am trying to run Filebeat using supervisord. But the above command doesn't work for me. I have to manually log into the container and start Filebeat using "service filebeat start"

Comment: @code_blue Can you please verify that the path to filebeat is correct? Depending on how you have installed Filebeat the path might be `/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat` (no `bin` dir).